# Codeigniter concatenate method name in model

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to:

```
$this->model->getUnit1()->result();
$this->model->getUnit2()->result();
$this->model->getUnit3()->result();
//etc....
```

from looping:

```
for ($i = 1; $i < 50; $i++) {
     ${'unit' . $i} = $this->model->'getUnit' . $i . '()'->result(); //ERROR
}
```

How do I make my code not error

Answer (score 1):

you cant "concatenate method name"

I think you need to refactor your model because its make no sense to have 50 function to do similar job

```
public function getUnit($i)
{
    //your model code here
}
```

and you can get your data with:

```
for ($i = 1; $i < 50; $i++) {
     ${'unit' . $i} = $this->model->getUnit($i)->result();
}
```